# Printing Various Sections of the Array at a time

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array called backupArray which has 3 first children and then those have their own children data under companies, pls, notes, etc.

I want to print the data like this in a table format where | represents a column

```
[0]['companies'] | [1]['companies'] | [2]['companies']
[0]['notes'] | [1]['notes'] | [2]['notes']
[0]['pls'] | [1]['pls'] | [2]['pls']
```

So I wrote the code below:

```
echo "<td>".$backupArray[0]['companies']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$backupArray[1]['companies']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$backupArray[2]['companies']."</td>";
```

Above code I need to change companies in the bracket with $row['Name'] so different rows I get from the query I did to the database. When I do it like below code doesn't work.

```
echo "<td>".$backupArray[0]['{$row['Name']}']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$backupArray[1]['{$row['Name']}']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$backupArray[2]['{$row['Name']}']."</td>";
```

How can I go about achieving what I need to accomplish here?

Comment: When you have `'{$row['Name']}'` just replace with `$row['Name']`

Comment: So like this?
echo "<td>".$backupArray[1]['$row['Name']']."</td>";

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Found it, writing

Answer (score 0):

Below is what works. I don't know why ' brackets cause problem in this case though. Anyone who knows drop your comment below please. Working Code:

```
echo "<td>".$backupArray[0][$row['Name']]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$backupArray[1][$row['Name']]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$backupArray[2][$row['Name']]."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

From comment above...

When you have `'{$row['Name']}'` just replace with `$row['Name']`

So as you have found the result would be...

```
echo "<td>".$backupArray[0][$row['Name']]."</td>";
```

There are two reasons -  the first is that as you use single quotes round the whole field, `'{$row['Name']}'` your second single quote acts as the end of the string `'{$row['` and so this is wrong.

The second reason - is that variable substitution doesn't work in single quotes so even `'{$row["Name"]}'` would just come out as `{$row["Name"]}`.  Always use double quotes if you want fields to be replaced with their value.

Lastly as you just want the value of the field - there is not need for all this as you can just use the field name itself!